# VBA - SQL - Realizar filtro com SELECT

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, select, vba

## Gostaria de uma ajuda na extração de informações de outra planilha por meio do SQL.

O link da planilha onde irá estabelecer a conexão e extrair as informações é este:  [Pelo Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TtBG_SFoqc_9YSKhqGpZKLXoggIsi5r2/view?usp=sharing)

O link da planilha onde é a Base de Dados, onde contém as informações para a extração é este: [Pelo Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17nii6o_ePPhk3owbG86GEcPi9OTsW0wH)

> Tenho uma planilha onde possui os campos:
>   **Nº Tel, Motivo de Envio, Data Ativação, Data Importação Data Alteração, Status.**
>
> Preciso importar todas elas, com alguns critérios (exceção):

- **Nº Tel** que não se repete e esteja com o **Status** (LIBERADO) não precisa ser importado.
- **Nº Tel** que não se repete e esteja com o **Status** (ANOMALIA TEMPORARIA, PENDENTE, EM ANÁLISE) precisa ser importado.
- Não precisa ser importada o Status (ANOMALIA DEFINITIVA)
- **Nº Tel** que se repete e possui no **Status** (ANOMALIA TEMPORARIA, PENDENTE, EM ANÁLISE) precisa ser importado.
- **NÃO IMPORTAR** os **Nº Tel** (números de telefones) que se repetem **SE** tiver em algum deles o Status **LIBERADO**, ou seja se tiver 4 números repetidos por exemplo, e em um deles aparecer o Status LIBERADO nenhum desses números será importado.

Eu tentei de muitas maneiras, mas sem sucesso, eu ainda sou um iniciante com SQL, eu fiz o código abaixo, mas ele não segue as regras mencionadas acima.

```
StrSql = "SELECT [Nº Tel], [Motivo de Envio], [Data Ativação], [Data Importação], [Data Alteração], Status FROM [export$] WHERE Status in ('ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA','PENDENTE','EM ANÁLISE')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vai ter que usar uma subquery, que nada mais é do que um `SELECT` dentro de outro `SELECT`. A query ficou assim:

```
SELECT [Nº Tel], [Motivo de Envio], [Data Ativação], [Data Importação], [Data Alteração], [Status]
FROM `C:\xxx\APURAR.xlsx`.`export$` AS export
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT aux.[Nº Tel]
    FROM `C:\xxx\APURAR.xlsx`.`export$` AS aux
    WHERE export.[Nº Tel] = aux.[Nº Tel] 
        AND aux.[Status] = 'LIBERADO'
)
AND [Status] IN ('ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA','PENDENTE','EM ANÁLISE')
ORDER BY [Nº Tel]
```

A subquery abaixo verifica se existe algum número com o **Status** (LIBERADO) e o `NOT EXISTS` exclui ele:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT aux.[Nº Tel]
    FROM `C:\xxx\APURAR.xlsx`.`export$` AS aux
    WHERE export.[Nº Tel] = aux.[Nº Tel] 
        AND aux.[Status] = 'LIBERADO'
```

O resultado ficou assim:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Excelente meu amigo funcionou perfeitamente, só que sou iniciante com Banco de Dados, você poderia me explicar cada linha que você escreveu e descrever o que cada coisa faz, pois não gosto de somente copiar e colar, mas sim de entender o que foi feito :D

Comment: Então, te recomendo buscar um livro de T-SQL. Ou fazer esse curso [gratuito na mva](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/querying-with-transact-sql-10530?)

Comment: Mas a explicação é como está na resposta mesmo. Só seram incluindos os telefones quando a subquery não achar nada, por isso o `NOT EXISTS`.  E faço a junção lógica da subquery com `export.[Nº Tel] = aux.[Nº Tel]`. Como as duas são na mesma tabela, eu chamo a tabela na subquery de `aux`.

Comment: Amigo, você tinha me ajudado da última vez, só que agora é um novo processo para realizar os filtros, você poderia me ajudar? as novas regras são essas: [regras aqui](https://ghostbin.com/paste/2fzrv) a base de dados continua sendo a mesma: [dados aqui](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TtBG_SFoqc_9YSKhqGpZKLXoggIsi5r2/view) se puder me ajudar agradeço!